# How to connect to one salesforce org from another salesforce org

Tags: apex, oauth2, org, loginflow

How to connect to a salesforce org to another salesforce org using web based login and without a connected app.

I want to connect to sandbox orgs from prod org and do not want to create connected apps. Is there a way we can login using the web based login flow ?

After creating names credential as @sfdcfox mentioned below, I get the Unauthorized access, 401 error. I used the named credential as follows

```
String restUrl = 'callout:TestNamedCredential/services/data/v42.0/limits';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(restUrl);
req.setMethod('GET');
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(restUrl);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setBody('UserName:{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Username)}');
    req.setBody('Password:{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}');

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this article(Connecting one Org to another via Rest API) :
https://cloudvista.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/connecting-one-salesforce-org-to-another-via-rest-api/

Note: this uses connected App but has all step by step details

Comment: I am looking for solution which does not involve connected apps. I want to connect to n number of sandboxes from prod